# sbt-docker cannot run echo pipe

Tags: sbt-docker

I am using sbt-docker and trying to setup ssh on docker by following this link: https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/.

sbt-docker seems not to understand below:

```
run("echo", "'root:root' | chpasswd")
```

Instead of changing the root user password, this run command simply prints string "'root:root' | chpasswd".

Similarly,

```
run("echo", "root:root", "&>", "rootpasswd.txt")
```

This command print "root:root &> rootpasswd.txt" instead of writing "root:root" into rootpasswd.txt file.

Any idea how to make sbt-docker correctly execute these echo commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Docker can run commands in 2 ways, shell form and exec form. The shell form will run your command in a shell.
sbt-docker supports both formats with the methods: `run` (exec) and `runShell` (shell).

Since you are using a pipe you need to run your command using a shell. This is what the `runShell` method is for:

```
runShell("echo", "root:root", "|", "chpasswd")
runShell("echo", "root:root", "&>", "rootpasswd.txt")
```

You can also use the `runRaw` method, which allowes you to freely use any form:

```
runRaw("echo root:root | chpasswd")
runRaw("echo root:root &> rootpasswd.txt")
```